# Tkinter problem with structure of tabulate table in tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, tabulate

I'm currently trying to print a table of data gathered from a database onto a GUI in tkinter, at the moment I'm using tabulate which runs fine in console, but as soon as I try to set the table as text as print as a label the table skews and the values are not aligned. I am still new to tkinter and so my code is by far not the most efficient or effective, any ideas on why this is happening or a way around?

```
        order = (key_1,name_1,price_1,quantity_1,total_1)
        table.append(order)
        count +=1
    print_table = (tabulate(table,headers=headers,tablefmt= "rst"))
    c.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    label_table = tk.Label(self,text=print_table)
    label_table.pack()
```

Expected Result:
!file:///var/folders/59/89rdtwpd4vnf6pv7pbd3l60m0000gn/T/com.apple.Safari/WebKitDropDestination-rwh55dGn/Screen%20Shot%202019-02-03%20at%2011.49.29%20PM.png

Actual Result:

!file:///var/folders/59/89rdtwpd4vnf6pv7pbd3l60m0000gn/T/com.apple.Safari/WebKitDropDestination-tZziKT9D/Screen%20Shot%202019-02-03%20at%2011.47.15%20PM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgG4C.png

Comment: You could give the `Treeview` widget a try: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/tree.html and http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend creating a grid of `tk.Entry` widgets where you place your headers and values in discrete entries. If you recorded the `tk.Entry` widget objects in a list you would be able to call on them individually outside of the loop if you preferred that. You could substitute the `tk.Label` widget in the place of `tk.Entry` with other formatting changes if you were partial to the `Label` widget.

```
tableWindow=tk.Toplevel()
tableHeaderList=["Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4"]

for i in range(height): #Rows
    for j in range(width): #Columns
        b = tk.Entry(tableWindow, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
        if i == 0:
            b.insert(0,tableHeaderList[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a monospaced font. I face the same problem and use
Cascadia Mono font and it worked. use the parameter `font=("Cascadia Mono", 10)` in the label. Hope it helps.